How to redirect in pac4j to home with google or facebook?
I am using cas apereo v6.6.15 with pac4j v5.4.6 and I am not being able to redirect to the sso home when I log in through Google or Facebook
In my build.gradle I have the following dependencies:
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-rest-authentication
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-authentication
mplementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-json-service-registry
    
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-authentication
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-authentication-api
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-api-authentication
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-web-api   
   
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow
implementation org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-pac4j-core

and in cas.properties I have included the properties:
cas.authn.pac4j.google.callback-url
cas.authn.pac4j.facebook.callback-url

each with the assignment of the home to which it should be redirected.
But, for some reason that I don't know, it is redirecting me to a home that is not the one I want, and no matter how much I have searched, I cannot find how that home is assigned, which continues to persist even though with the previous properties I assign the home to which I need to redirect.
Previously I had cas v6.1 and updated it to v6.6.15.
The host where it resolved in 6.1 was test-sso.domain.com, but now we change to a aws-sso.domain.com.
But when i setup the CAS on 6.6.x for delegated oauth for google or facebook, the callback url is redirect me to test-sso.domain.com and not for the actual host configured aws-sso.domain.com and we dont have any test-sso.domain.com setting in anywhere
Additionally, Catalina's log shows callbackUrl: https://test-sso.domain.com.uy/cas/login, which is the old domain and I don't understand where it comes from.

The callback URL in CAS (something like /cas/login/GoogleClient) is used to finish the delegated login process.
So you cannot change its value to your home URL.
After a delegated authentication, the CAS server redirects the user to the original CAS service URL.
